# Mockito 2 + Junit 5 NoSuchMethodError on AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to integrate JUnit 5 under Eclipse Oxygen3.
The project already has Mockito 2.

I have done all steps suggested in https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension like so:

Dependencies:

- junit-jupiter-engine 5.5.0
- junit-jupiter-api 5.5.0
- junit-vintage-engine 5.5.0
- junit-platform-runner 1.5.0
- mockito-core 2.28.2
- mockito-junit-jupiter 2.28.2

Code:

```
public class Jupiter {

    public boolean isAlpha() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Test Code:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given; 
import java.util.Date;  
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class JupiterTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Jupiter jupiter;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        //usually some stuff here
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("heading jupiter - make it so")
    public void test() {
        boolean result = jupiter.isAlpha();

        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, running tests fail.

Have anyone stumbled upon a similar problem? Is it something general or my project specific problem?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.retrieveAnnotationFromTestClasses(MockitoExtension.java:178)
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$null$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:126)
...
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$null$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:226)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:116)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure why need all that vintage and platform stuff.. Your tests are `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

I would do this:

**1)** Remove all the annotations from the class level

**2)** Init Mockito:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

**3)** These deps should be sufficient:

```
junit-jupiter 5.5.0
mockito-core 2.28.2
```

Comment: Well I guess I have miss read the article on baeldung. Removing other dependencies and injecting mocks in setup method fixed problem. Too bad @InjectMocks stopped working but I guess that's another issue to research for. Thanks for help!

Comment: UPDATE: actually I need **`junit-vintage-engine`** and **`junit-platform-runner`** because they provide **backword compatibility** with tests that are still written in **JUnit4**.

Answer (score 0):

mockito-junit-jupiter 2.28.2 allows you to use this way, this may possibly solve your problem.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoSettings;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.quality.Strictness.LENIENT;

@MockitoSettings(strictness = LENIENT)
public class JupiterTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private Jupiter jupiter;

   @BeforeEach
   public void setup() {
      //usually some stuff here
   }

   @Test
   @DisplayName("heading jupiter - make it so")
   public void test() {
      boolean result = jupiter.isAlpha();

      assertThat(result).isTrue();
   }
}
```

Comment: Strickness Lanient is supposed to change behaviour of Mockito with unused stubs. It didn't help during test execution under Eclipse, but helped with "Unnecessary stubbing" that was appearing while running tests on maven thou.